# Phonegap.js on second html page

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I basically have two pages in my phonegap application that I am building with PGB (index.html and main.html), that both use angular.js. Index.html is a login for the app, which redirects to main.html afterwards. All my plugins and phonegap.js are being injected fine into main, but none of the inline JS (alerts on doc ready, device ready, window load) are firing, let alone phonegap.js being loaded as well.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Script Includes:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script> <script>alert("inside pg");</script>
<script src="childbrowser.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>alert("here");</script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/maskedInput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.joyride.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Scripts:

```
 alert("p2 adding")
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("main.html: device is ready");
}

$(window).load(function(){
  alert("window.load happening");
})
</script>

<script>

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-42023187-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-42023187-1', 'openvino.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var objectToLike = window.location;
  var FBactivated = false;

    FB.init({
      appId      : '659381964079214', // App ID
      channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true,
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        getFriends();
        testAPI();
        FBactivated = true;
      }
    });

  function getFriends() {
    var fbUserIDs = []
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        if(response.data) {
          $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
              var id = friend.id;
              fbUserIDs.push(id);
          });
          var dataString = "fbUserIDs="+fbUserIDs.join();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            async: false,
            url: "http://m.openvino.com/Scripts/faveMatch.php"
          }).done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          window.localStorage.setItem("fbFriends", data);
          console.log("Saved");
          });
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
  }

    function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      //console.log(response, response.email);
      var dataString2 = "id=" + response.id;
      dataString2 += "&first_name=" + response.first_name;
      dataString2 += "&last_name=" + response.last_name;
      dataString2 += "&email=" + response.email; 
      console.log(dataString2);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://m.openvino.com/Scripts/fbconnect.php",
        data: dataString2
      }).done(function(data){
        var dataJSON = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (dataJSON[0].STATUS == "FAILURE") {
          //console.log(dataJSON[0].MESSAGE);
          return false;
        } else if (dataJSON[0].STATUS == "SUCCESS") {
          window.localStorage.setItem('email',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.email);
          window.localStorage.setItem('password',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.password);
          window.localStorage.setItem('name_first',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.name_first);
          window.localStorage.setItem('name_last',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.name_last);
          window.localStorage.setItem('uID',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.uID);
          window.localStorage.setItem('phone',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.phone);
          window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime',dataJSON[0].COOKIE.firstTime);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function fbLogout() {
    if (FBactivated) { 
      try {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          window.location.href = "index.html";
        });
      } catch (err) {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
      }
    } else {
      window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {   
    alert("document.ready loaded");

    $("#logmeout").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.localStorage.clear();

        fbLogout();
        return false;
    });

    $('.back_btn').click(function(e) {
      $('.profile_menu').hide();
      history.back();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      $('.profile_menu').hide();
    })

    $('.profile_btn').click(function(e) {
      $('.profile_menu').slideToggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });

    $('.profile_menu a').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(e) {
        $('.profile_menu').hide();
      });
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="OpenVino">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="header-wrap">
  <header>
    <div ng-show="(page != 'list')" class="back_btn"></div> 
    <a href="#" onclick="launchBrowser(http://facebook.com)"><img src="imgs/logo_only.png" alt="OpenVino" /></a>
    <div class="profile_btn"></div>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="profile_menu">
  <a href="#/users/">My Favorites</a> 
  <a href="#/aboutus/">Contact OpenVino</a>
  <a href="#/lifestyle/">Images</a>
  <a href="#" id="logmeout">Logout</a>
</div>
<div class="content {{page}}" ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a simple, but disheartening solution: You have to turn your multipage app into a one page app. Unfortunate how phonegap advertises that you can take your HTML, CSS, and JS and build it natively. All of the .js loaded on the second page wouldnt work until I changed my login to a partial and fooled around with the routing.